# How to access iCloud photos using react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, icloud, cloudkit

I'm using react-native expo to create an app

I'm trying to access user's iCloud photos and I'm a bit lost.

I found CloudKit but this doesn't look like what I'm looking for. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Looking around more, it almost seems like this is not possible due to privacy issues? I may be wrong.

My goal: I want to retrieve some form of link of the photos from user's iCloud that I can provide it to  component for rendering.

Any help and pointers are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide more context for the above question? where exactly do you want to access iCloud images, any image picker you are using?

Comment: @DevVyaas I want to access iCloud images from the app that's using react-native and expo. For image picker, I'm just planning to use regular <Image> since I'm only going to support images.